# !ISSET in IF statement not working

Tags: php, isset

I have an if statement that I want to run if either the session OR cookie is not set.

The following is my code,

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['redirected']) OR !isset($_COOKIE['redirected']) ) {
```

The following doesn't throw an error, but it is not working as i expected it to. The statement is not run if there is no session set.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of how I can get around this?

Comment: both of `!isset($_SESSION['redirected']` are equal here ?

Comment: What does `var_dump($_SESSION['redirected'], $_COOKIE['redirected']);` output?

Comment: @Farzad read again, one is _SESSION and the other is _COOKIE.

Comment: Do you mean 'empty()' rather than '!isset()'? '!isset()' will return **false** for an empty string (''). 'empty()', on the other hand, will return **true** for an empty string. confused? i am ;-/

Comment: @Veda yea, the question has been edited after my comment :D

Comment: Must they both have values? 'cos the statement you provide will not do what you want in the case of empty strings. I should have asked this the first time ;-/

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you missed to start the session `session_start();` otherwise, this statement is true:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['redirected']) || !isset($_COOKIE['redirected']) ) {

}
```

This statement is true if either session or cookie not set.